# How do I use condition formatting for data?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to have data exported into an excel file that has condition formatting applied to it:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
wb  = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A10',
                          ColorScaleRule(start_type='min', start_color='AA0000',
                                         end_type='max', end_color='00AA00')
                         )

worksheet.conditional_formatting.add("O2:O295", color_scale_rule)
workbook.save(filename="sample_conditional_formatting_color_scale.xlsx")
```

I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'conditional_formatting'
```

I am aiming for this:

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged openpyxl? You're using xlsxwriter as the engine... Also your variables seem inconsistent. Please make sure this is a [mre]

Comment: This looks like some carelessly copy pasted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were creating your pandas DataFrame incorrectly.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
path = 'pandas_simple.xlsx'
df.to_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
wb  = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb['Sheet1']


# Add a three-color scale
ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A10',
                ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='AA0000',
                            mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='0000AA',
                            end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='00AA00')
                              )

wb.save(filename="sample_conditional_formatting_color_scale.xlsx")
```

Output:

[image]

Tweaking the colorscale to match your expected output is left as an exercise for the reader.